# How to expedite data populating from excel to word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a set of data to populate from excel to word document. Each word document will have more than 20 bookmarks to be filled in. With the current codes I have, it will populate each bookmarks one by one until it finishes. It usually takes about few minutes to finish filling a word document, which is really slow. How can I change the codes to fill in all the bookmarks like in a flash/seconds, something like mail merge without waiting. I have tried Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic but it's not working.

I TRIED USING MAIL MERGE, but it won't be able to do certain things that excel VBA can.

Hoping for some help on this.

Here are the codes :

```
Private Sub NTStep2a_Click()
Dim db As Object
Set db = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry B")
Dim la As Object
Set la = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LA")
Dim lh As Object
Set lh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LtrHead")
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim strName As String
strName = Sheet15.Range("C67")
Dim Mark As String
Dim Txt As String
Dim BmkStart As Long
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open Filename:="Z:\abc\123\blabla.doc", ReadOnly:=True objWord.ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="stwppj312"
With objWord.ActiveDocument


'letter referencing
Mark = "dev_ref"
Txt = db.Range("C808").Value
If .Bookmarks.Exists(Mark) Then
With .Bookmarks(Mark).Range
BmkStart = .Start
.Text = Txt
End With
.Bookmarks.Add Mark, .Range(BmkStart, BmkStart + Len(Txt))
End If
.Fields.Update

Mark = "stwp_ref"
Txt = db.Range("C66").Value
If .Bookmarks.Exists(Mark) Then
With .Bookmarks(Mark).Range
BmkStart = .Start
.Text = Txt
End With
.Bookmarks.Add Mark, .Range(BmkStart, BmkStart + Len(Txt))
End If
.Fields.Update

Mark = "date"
Txt = db.Range("C23").Value
If .Bookmarks.Exists(Mark) Then
With .Bookmarks(Mark).Range
BmkStart = .Start
.Text = Txt
End With
.Bookmarks.Add Mark, .Range(BmkStart, BmkStart + Len(Txt))
End If
.Fields.Update

.Bookmarks("lae11").Range.Text = la.Range("F16").Value
.Bookmarks("la12").Range.Text = la.Range("C17").Value
.Bookmarks("lae12").Range.Text = la.Range("F17").Value

objWord.ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="stwppj312", NoReset:=False, Type:=wdAllowOnlyReading, EnforceStyleLock:=True
objWord.Run ("ProcessRanges")
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="Z:\STWP General\Auto Populate\AP LOAN v2\Saved Docs\" & "Step2a " & strName & ".doc"


End With
objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you NOT doing this with mailmerge?

Comment: I've mentioned in the post. Mail merge won't do certain things that Excel VBA can do.

Comment: Such as? See, for example, my **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html; my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html; and my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html. There is a vast amount mailmerges can do that you probably haven't considered. In any event, you seem only to be copying data - which even the most basic mailmerge can do.

Comment: Extra columns/rows are left in word doc to be filled in, and there are times that not all columns/rows will be filled, hence the empty columns/rows. so i have automated to delete the empty columns/rows after filling the doc. but by having mail merge field, the excel vba is not recognizing it as empty columns/rows.

Comment: That's just poor design. If you have tables to create, Word can do that with DATABASE fields, with no left-over rows, etc.

Comment: mail merge somehow can't recognize data for more than 200 columns right? i have more than 200 columns data. it just stop recognizing data till certain column.

Comment: «mail merge somehow can't recognize data for more than 200 columns right?» Yes. The code you posted goes nowhere near that, however.